# Calling a print method from another class with primitive data types in it

Tags: java, methods, int, call, primitive

I have been programming in Java using BlueJ for 2 months now and I need some help with an assignment. I am making a basic Vehicle Purchase data entry program. I need to call the `printPurchaseDate()` method from the `PurchaseDate` class. The problem I am faced with is that the print statement has three int values: year, month, and day. When I try to call this method in the Vehicle class in the `printDetails()` method, it tells me that I need a return, if I take away the void I have to label the method as a string. However it doesn't work then because it holds three int variables inside it that conflict with the string method. How can I go about doing this? I basically want to print all of my information including the `purchaseDate`.  My apologies in advance if I did not present my question properly, this is my first post. Thank you for your help.

I have two classes: Purchase Date and Vehicle.

My vehicle class has this method, designed to print out my information:

```
public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("Customer:" + " " +
    customer.getFullName());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Description:" + " " + 
    getVehiclePurchased());
    PurchaseDate.printPurchaseDate();
}
```

Im having issues with printing  the date from my PurchaseDate class in my Vehicle class's "printDetails()" method.

```
/**
  * The Purchase data class
  */

public class PurchaseDate {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    private static final int CURRENT_YEAR = 2014;
    private static final int LAST_MONTH = 12;
    private static final int LAST_DAY = 31;

    /**
     * default constructor
     */
    public PurchaseDate() {
    }

    /**
     * @param year to initialize theYear field
     * @param month to initialize theMonth field
     * @param day to initialize theDay field
     */

    public PurchaseDate(int theYear, int theMonth, int theDay) {
    setYear(theYear);
    setMonth(theMonth);
    setDay(theDay);

    if (year < 1900 || year > 2014) {
            System.out.println("The year value can be no greater than the current year");
        } else {
            this.year = year; }
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            System.out.println("The month value must be between 1 and 12");
        } else {
            this.month = month; }        
    if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            System.out.println("The day value must be between 1 and 31");
       } else {
            this.day = day; }
    }        
    //Mutators and Accessors    
    /**
     * @return year
     */
    public int getYear() {  
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * @return month
     */
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    /**
     * @return day
     */
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * @param the year
     */
    public final void setYear(int newYear) {
        year = newYear;
    }

    /**
     * @param the month
     */
    public final void setMonth(int newMonth) {
        month = newMonth;
    }

    /**
     * @param the day
     */
    public final void setDay(int newDay) {
        day = newDay;
    }

    /**
     * prints the purchase date
     */
    public void printPurchaseDate() {
        System.out.println("The purchase date is:" + " " + year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

    }
}
```

I basically want my `System.out.println` to print out the date
that I have in my `PurchaseDate` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("Customer:" + " " +
    customer.getFullName());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Description:" + " " + 
    getVehiclePurchased());
    PurchaseDate.printPurchaseDate();
}
```

The basic problem in your code is that your calling the printPurchaseDate() in static way
but it is a non static method.
You have to create the refrence of PurchaseDate class and calll the method with the refrence

```
PurchaseDate pd = new PurchaseDate();
public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("Customer:" + " " +
    customer.getFullName());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Description:" + " " + 
    getVehiclePurchased());
    pd.printPurchaseDate();
}
```

Other thing you can do it to declair method static.

```
public static void printPurchaseDate(){
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Non static method can not be called with class name they need to excess with class reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `printPurchaseDate()` returns `void` and `println()` expects something (i.e. a String).  To fix it,

```
public String printPurchaseDate() {
    return "The purchase date is: " + String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(day);
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: How so?  Why don't you post your code so that we don't have to guess.  Your original problem was "why the println method was not working.  We explained to you why it wasn't. Now, you have another problem. Post your code, and that way we don't have to play '20 questions'

Comment: If I use this method I run into a problem because "year", "month", and "day" are int values and the method is a string. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I just edited the method. `String.valueOf()` turns those primitive values into Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these ways will solve your problem:

```
public String getPurchaseDate() {
    return "The purchase date is:" + " " + year + "-" + month + "-" + day; 
}

public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("Customer:" + " " +
    customer.getFullName());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Description:" + " " +
    getVehiclePurchased());
    System.out.println(PurchaseDate.getPurchaseDate());
}
```

OR

```
public void printPurchaseDate() {
    System.out.println("The purchase date is:" + " " + year + "-" + month + "-" + day); 
}

public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("Customer:" + " " +
    customer.getFullName());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Description:" + " " +
    getVehiclePurchased());
    PurchaseDate.printPurchaseDate();
}
```